# Elements in the same coset and the Cayley Diagram

Tags: group-theory, intuition, cayley-graphs

A question from *Visual group theory,* by Nathan Carter. In a Cayley diagram,  if $aH$ is a coset of a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ and $b$ belongs to $aH$, why is it that every node that can be reached from $a$ using generators of subgroup $H$ can also be reached from $b$ using those same generators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points which can be reached from $a$ by a product of generators of $H$ are precisely the point in $\{a h\mid h\in H\}$ because every element in $H$ can be written as a product of generators of $H$ (by definition of generators). This set is equal to $aH$ and so as $b\in aH$ it follows that $b$ can be reached by generators from $H$. This is essentially saying that $aH=bH$ for all $b\in aH$.

Let's make this slightly more explicit. Suppose $b=ah$ for some $h\in H$. Consider the point $c$ which we can reach from $a$ by multiplying by some element in $H$, so $c=ah'$ for some $h'\in H$. Well then $c=(bh^{-1})h'=b(h^{-1}h)$ and so we can also reach $c$ from $b$ because $h^{-1}h$ is in $H$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But it would be helpful if you explain how it will be possible if the point lies outside H?

Comment: If what point lies outside of $H$?

Comment: @Danial Rust if the point to be reached from a and b belonging to H,lie outside H?

Comment: Unless $aH=H$, you can't reach points in $H$ from $a$ using just translations by elements from $H$. The only point you can reach in $G$ are points in $aH$.

Comment: I've added a slightly more concrete explanation. Hope it helps.